# Can't use auto generated wrappers classes for bidimensional arrays with Axis2 top down approach

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, wrapper

I've created a web service with Axis2 version 1.6 using the top down
approach from a WSDL. Everything worked fine for a while (i.e. the webservice was
deployed).
Then I started implementing the web service skeleton
that axis2 generated. The problem arose when I reached a method that
should return a `String[][]`, of course it was wrapped since Axis2
generates the return objects as wrapped objects. Turns out that the
wrapper class contained a class (`StringArrayArray`). When I tried to set
that `StringArrayArray` I realized that was another wrapper, when I
went to check how to set the value to a `StringArrayArray` it only
contains one way to set it `setValue(org.apache.axiom.om.OMElement[] value)`.
I've looked everywhere and I still can't figure out how to use that
interface to return the `String[][]` I need to return.
In another method that returned a `String[]` (That was wrapped as a
`StringArray`) I found that just creating an object of `StringArray` type
and setting it like `StringArray.setValue(String[])` it worked.
Unfortunately it wasn't the same with `String[][]`.

I need to know how to make it work in order to be able to return de
data in the webservice.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just treat the String[] like a String[][] array; essentially, they are the same, just iterated differently.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm not sure I understand what you're saying, I can't change the return type `String[][]` of the method to `String[]` because the system that will use the Web service already exists and can't be changed and it receives a `String[][]`. But I'm not sure if that's what you are suggesting.